# htaccess folder to subdomain rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

How can `example.com/blog` seamlessly show the content of `blog.example.com` without a redirect?

Not this:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog http://blog.example.com [R=301,L]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to occur, both the domain and subdomain would have to be running from the same directory of files. Then you could just rewrite the `/blog` path to the same file that the subdomain is using to run. Depending on your permissions, it could be possible to specify a `../` path to the file that it's using if you get the directories right.

However, anytime you specify a full domain path in a rewrite rule, Apache will *always* redirect the request. You can't get around that.

Answer (score 0):

if **example.com/blog** and **blog.example.com**(subdomain) both points to same directory(`blog`). Then you can directly access the specified path without any redirection.